# Header getting messed up when scrolling down, then back up

Tags: html, css

On the website of a client, I got this weird thing going on. Everything is fine, but when you scroll down and then back up the header gets a large white area of where the adress/contact bar is.

This is the site:
[rijschool-wolvega.nl](http://www.rijschool-wolvega.nl)

I'm not an expert in css, and have been looking for days. Please help me out! :)
(I don't know what info you guys need, but I'll update this when asked)

Comment: I think it's a JS problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you scroll back up, the header div losses it's `stuck` class:

### Before scroll:

```
<div class="header stuck">
   ...
</div>
```

### Scrolled down 1:

```
<div class="header stuck">
   ...
</div>
```

### Scrolled down 2:

```
<div class="header stuck header-scrolled">
   ...
</div>
```

### Scroll back up:

```
<div class="header">
   ...
</div>
```

Your problem lies in `waypoint-sticky.min.js`:

```
@line 22 | stuckClass: 'stuck';
```

And here:

```
@line 51 | return this.removeClass(this.data('stuckClass'));
```

Which removes the class

Comment: Indeed this was the problem. I removed the code in "waypoint-sticky.min.js" and it's all good now. Thanks a lot all for helping me out! <3

Answer (score 1):

i think you have applied some jquery on scroll ... and on scrolling you missing out the *stuck* class in your header !

```
<div class="header stuck">
```

This is should be there on scroll down...

Answer (score 0):

change your css of class topcontactinfo

```
 margin-bottom: 30px !important;
 color: #fff !important;
 z-index: 1000 !important;
 margin-left: 46%;
 margin-top: 2%;
```

it will work fine